# Lightning component description attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is there a way I can use JavaScript to get the description of a component:

```
<aura:component description="ckz_PIM_ScreenOptionsDisplay">
```

Comment: What would be the purpose behind this, out of curiosity?

Comment: Are you looking to use design attribute?

Comment: I was looking for a way to determine what component I'm currently in without defining an attribute for that.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak When/Why would you need that? What is the use case that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @JayantDas I have buttons that will take the user to the previous or next screens in the component.  I wanted to determine which component I'm currently "in".  The other option I have is to create an attribute for the screen name and add it to each component being displayed.